# Use Ubuntu on Tablet with mouse/keyboard?

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

So here is the thing...
I have a Nexus 7 (2012), and the digitizer broke on me. To have it fixed would be pretty close to simply buying a new one. An OGT cable is super cheap.

If I could install Ubuntu on the 2012 Nexus 7, could I plug in an OGT then a mouse/keyboard, and use Ubuntu that way? I know Unity is still work in progress, so for now I am open to other environments. Would this work?

Thank you for your time and answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried connecting a keyboard to my Nexus 4 and it didn't work, I'm sure it's doable with a bit of tinkering but at this point it is not a plug and play thing.

Also keep in mind that Nexus 7 2012 is no longer officially supported and that Ubuntu images for it are outdated. The list of currently supported devices is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).

Your second option could be to do just a plain Ubuntu install rather than Ubuntu Touch as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) Keep in mind that this wiki page was last updated a year ago though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. Hmm, I am thinking once Unity-next becomes more mature, you could switch from tablet interface to traditional desktop (you know since its all the same code). Maybe I will hold on to the N7 and see if that becomes true.